# How to optionally set Winston transports when logging to Stackdriver from GKE

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, winston, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have a Node.js app which runs in a Docker container in Google Kubernetes Engine. I have set up a logging class which uses `Winston` (v3.2.1) with two transports defined; one to log to the console and one to log to Stackdriver (using `@google-cloud/logging-winston` (v3.0.0)).

With both transports defined, all is good and I can see the logs in Stackdriver. The console logs go to `projects/[project-id]/logs/stdout` and the Stackdriver logs go to `projects/[project-id]/logs/winston_log`.

However, I want to configure the logger so that when debugging locally, logs are only sent to the console and when running in GKE, logs are only sent to Stackdriver, as follows:

```
  // Configure console logger
  private readonly consoleLogger = new winston.transports.Console({
    format: combine(
      colorize(),
      simple(),
      printf(context => {
        return `[${context.level}]${context.message}`;
      }),
    ),
  });

  // Configure Stackdriver logger
  private readonly stackdriverLogger = new LoggingWinston({
    serviceContext: {
      service: this.serviceName,
    },
  });

  // Create Winston logger
  private readonly logger = winston.createLogger({
    level: process.env.LOG_LEVEL || 'info',
    format: json(),
    defaultMeta: {
      service: this.serviceName,
    },
    // This line does not work:
    transports: [process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? this.consoleLogger : this.stackdriverLogger],
  });
```

The aim here is that if the `NODE_ENV` is `development`, use the console logger, otherwise use the Stackdriver logger. However, when I deploy this to GKE, I see the following errors in the Stackdriver console log (and nothing in `projects/[project-id]/logs/winston_log`):

```
[winston] Attempt to write logs with no transports { // Logged message }
```

When I run this code locally on my dev machine with `NODE_ENV=development`, I see the logs in my local console and if I set `NODE_ENV=production` I see the logs in Stackdriver.

If I remove the ternary operator and have both transports defined and deploy to GKE, I do not see the above error and logging works correctly to both transports:

```
transports: [this.consoleLogger, this.stackdriverLogger],
```

Can anyone help me to configure this correctly?

#### EDIT

Added the full `Logger.ts` file for context:

```js
import { LoggerService } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as winston from 'winston';
const { colorize, combine, json, printf, simple } = winston.format;
import { LoggingWinston } from '@google-cloud/logging-winston';
import cls from 'cls-hooked';
import { ConfigManager } from '../config';
import { TraceId } from '../middleware/traceId/constants';

export class Logger implements LoggerService {
  private readonly serviceName: string = process.env.SERVICE_NAME;

  private readonly consoleLogger = new winston.transports.Console({
    format: combine(
      colorise(),
      simple(),
      printf(context => {
        return `[${context.level}]${context.message}`;
      }),
    ),
  });

  private stackdriverLogger = new LoggingWinston({
    serviceContext: {
      service: this.serviceName,
    },
  });

  private readonly logger = winston.createLogger({
    level: process.env.LOG_LEVEL || 'info',
    format: json(),
    defaultMeta: {
      service: this.serviceName,
    },
    transports: [process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? this.consoleLogger : this.stackdriverLogger]
  });

  constructor(private readonly context?: string) {}

  public verbose(message: string, context?: string) {
    const log = this.buildLog(message, context);
    this.logger.verbose(log.message, log.metadata);
  }

  public debug(message: string, context?: string) {
    const log = this.buildLog(message, context);
    this.logger.debug(log.message, log.metadata);
  }

  public log(message: string, context?: string) {
    const log = this.buildLog(message, context);
    this.logger.info(log.message, log.metadata);
  }

  public warn(message: string, context?: string) {
    const log = this.buildLog(message, context);
    this.logger.warn(log.message, log.metadata);
  }

  public error(message: string, trace?: string, context?: string) {
    const log = this.buildLog(message, context, trace);
    this.logger.error(log.message, log.metadata);
  }

  private buildLog(message: string, context?: string, trace?: string) {
    const ctx = context || this.context;
    const traceId = this.getTraceId();

    return {
      message: `[${ctx}] ${message}`,
      metadata: {
        traceId,
        source: ctx,
        stackTrace: trace,
      },
    };
  }

  private getTraceId(): string {
    const clsNamespace = cls.getNamespace(TraceId.Namespace);
    if (!clsNamespace) {
      return null;
    }
    return clsNamespace.get(TraceId.Key);
  }
}
```

Comment: can you post the full file?  are you referencing `this` outside of a class method?

Comment: I've edited the question with the full source file.

Comment: I think the issue is in how you're setting up nestjs `LoggerService`. There's nothing wrong with the way you're using `NODE_ENV`

Comment: I've narrowed it down to not being an issue with my code but an environmental issue with my GKE/GCP setup. When the application starts up in GKE, I get this error in Stackdriver error reporting: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FetchError: request to http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/instance failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 169.254.169.254:80`. This apparently breaks the `LoggingWinston` logger and causes the `[winston] Attempt to write logs with no transports` error in the container logs. I've opened a support case with Google and will post an answer here once I have a fix.

Comment: @AndrewRidout any solution?

Comment: @boudlal Yes, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the problem was the `@google-cloud/logging-winston` package had a bug in it which caused it to throw this error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FetchError: request to http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/instance failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 169.254.169.254:80
```

This has now been fixed in version 3.0.6 - see https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-logging-winston/issues/389#issuecomment-593727968.

After updating `@google-cloud/logging-winston`, the Winston logging is working correctly for me in Stackdriver.